# Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json' error when an async method is executed

Tags: c#, json, azure, c#-4.0, azure-iot-hub

In my mvc application I'm calling one async method, on button click, which will register device into iot hub.

The code works fine in the console app but is giving an issue in the mvc app.

error:

> The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Azure.Devices.HttpClientHelper' threw an exception.

Inner exception :

> Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Newtonsoft.Json packages is already installed into project 10.0.3 version 
code

```
  public async Task<ActionResult> AddDeviceAsync()
    {         
        Device device;
        try
        {
            connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultIoTHubConnection"];          

            registryManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);

            List<string> collection = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                collection.Add("dummy_device_" + i);
            }

            foreach (var deviceId in collection)
            {
                try
                {
                    // register device into IoT hub 
                    device = await registryManager.AddDeviceAsync(new Device(deviceId)); // getting exception here
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the package and re-adding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this problem arises when the CLR executes compiled code and it is not able to find an assembly in the app domain.

The idea here is that the code you are executing was compiled by referencing the version 6.0.0.0 of Newtonsoft.Json, but at runtime you are executing that code in an application domain where the referenced assembly is not available (or the referenced version of the assembly is not available).

Does your asp.net mvc project reference the Newtonsoft.Json nuget package ? What version of the package are you referencing ?

Comment: If Newtonsoft.Json is already installed in the project, then you have to add an assembly binding redirection inside your web.config file. You are referencing the version 10.0.0.3, while the external library you are using was compiled by referencing a different version (version 6.0.0.0). This means that, at runtime, you must redirect all the requests for Newtonsoft.Json to the version 10.0.0.3 that you are referencing. The only way to do that is applying an [assembly binding redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions)

Comment: Before writing the assembly binding redirection, you must verify the **assembly version** of Newtonsoft Json, which is different from the **nuget package version**. When you write an assembly binding redirection you **must** refer to the assembly version, not the nuget package version. In other words, in order to write a working redirection, you must verify what assembly version corresponds with the version of the nuget package that you are referencing.